# Rechart for customized dot in linechart

Tags: typescript, svg, linechart, recharts

I am following this for customized dot in line chart : https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomizedDotLineChart

In my graph I have 4 lines and for each line I need different shape for datapoints.

I followed the link, it worked for svg provided in link, but I need shapes like, circle, triange, rectangle/square, diamond

Here is my code,

```
const CustomizedDot = (props) => {
    const { cx, cy, dataKey } = props;

    if (dataKey === 'A') {
        return (
            <svg >
                <rect  />
            </svg>
        );
    }
    if (dataKey === 'B') {
        return (
            <svg ">
                <polygon  points="0 40,40 80,80 40,40 0" />
            </svg>
        );
    }
    if (dataKey === 'C') {
        return (
            <svg >
                <circle  />
            </svg>
        );
    }
    if (dataKey === 'D') {
        return (
            <svg >
                <polygon points="50 15, 100 100, 0 100"/>
            </svg>
        );
    }
};
```

and linechart is generated like this

```
<LineChart
                data={data.map((data) => ({
                    ...data,
                    date: data.date,
                }))}
            >
                <XAxis dataKey="date" />
                <YAxis />
                <Tooltip />
                <Legend />
                {(Object.keys(lineConfig) as TimeSeriesMetricKey[]).reduce(
                    (items: React.ReactElement[], key) => {
                        return [
                            ...items,
                            <Line
                                key={key}
                                dataKey={key}
                                name={lineConfig[key].legendLabel}
                                stroke={lineConfig[key].color}
                                strokeWidth={2}
                                activeDot={{r : 8}}
                                dot={<CustomizedDot />}
                            />,
                        ];
                    },
                    []
                )}
            </LineChart>
```

where I did something wrong that shapes not coming as per condition in SVG, it shows all are circle shape for all the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you provided, it seems there might be a small issue in your `CustomizedDot` component. It looks like you forgot to add the necessary attributes to the `SVG` shapes, such as `cx`, `cy`, and `r` for circles. Below is the updated code:

```
const CustomizedDot = (props) => {
    const { cx, cy, dataKey } = props;

    if (dataKey === 'A') {
        return (
            <svg>
                <rect x={cx - 4} y={cy - 4} width={8} height={8} />
            </svg>
        );
    }
    if (dataKey === 'B') {
        return (
            <svg>
                <polygon points={`${cx},${cy - 4} ${cx + 4},${cy + 4} ${cx - 4},${cy + 4}`} />
            </svg>
        );
    }
    if (dataKey === 'C') {
        return (
            <svg>
                <circle cx={cx} cy={cy} r={4} />
            </svg>
        );
    }
    if (dataKey === 'D') {
        return (
            <svg>
                <polygon points={`${cx - 2},${cy - 4} ${cx + 2},${cy - 4} ${cx},${cy + 4}`} />
            </svg>
        );
    }
};
```

Here, we are using the `cx` and `cy` attributes to position the shapes correctly based on the data point coordinates, and the appropriate attributes like width, `height`, `r`, and points have been added for each shape to make them display correctly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: how to add shapes in tooltip

Comment: @hetalgohel please specify a bit more, thanks.